# Limit and order_by in subquery sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to retrieve in a fastapi endpoint a list of a pydantic model that consists in some attributes of a `Subcategory` sqlalchemy model and an attribute that is also a list of a `ShowCommerceToSubcategory` pydantic model that matches the respective `Commerce` sqlalchemy model.  I want to be able to limit and order_by the results of the inner `Commerce` query.

So far I have a class method in my `Category` model with a very simple query that takes a certain category id and retrieves all the associated subcategories:

```
@classmethod
def get_subcategory_commerce(cls, id: int, db: Session, number_of_commerces: int = 5):
    subcategories = db.query(Subcategory)\
        .filter(Subcategory.main_category_id == id)\
        .all()
```

My response model looks like this:

```
class ShowSubcategoryCommerce(SQLModel):
    id: int
    main_category_id: int
    name: str
    description: str | None
    icon: str | None
    commerces: list[ShowCommerceToSubcategory]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

When I use the class method described above, I get somewhat the expected result. However, I want to be able to limit the results of the `ShowCommerceToSubcategory` model to 5 and show them in descendent order  by an attribute that my `Commerce` sqlalchemy model has, and that it is called importance.

I have tried this query to achieve this, but it is failing and not showing all the commerces within the respective subcategories:

```
subq = db.query(Commerce)\
    .join(Commerce.subcategories)\
    .order_by(Subcategory.id, Commerce.importance.desc())\
    .limit(number_of_commerces)\
    .subquery()

subcategories = db.query(Subcategory)\
    .filter(Subcategory.main_category_id == id)\
    .outerjoin(subq, Subcategory.commerces)\
    .options(contains_eager(Subcategory.commerces, alias=subq))\
    .order_by(Subcategory.id, subq.c.importance.desc())\
    .all()
```

Note that there is a many to many relationship between the `Commerce` and `Subcategory` tables/models

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're experiencing is likely due to the way SQL handles `LIMIT` in subqueries. When you specify `LIMIT` in your subquery, it's limiting the total number of `Commerce` objects returned, not the number of `Commerce` objects per Subcategory. Thus, if you have multiple `Subcategory` objects, your current query could return all the `Commerce` objects for one `Subcategory` and none for the others.

To achieve the result you want, you will need to use a window function to rank the Commerce objects within each Subcategory, and then filter based on this rank. In `SQLAlchemy`, you can use `func.row_number()` to do this.

Here is a rough example of how you could adjust your query:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func, desc

# Create a window function that ranks Commerce objects within each Subcategory
window = func.row_number().over(
    partition_by=Subcategory.id, order_by=Commerce.importance.desc()
).label("rn")

# Create a subquery that includes the rank
subq = (
    db.query(Commerce, window)
    .join(Commerce.subcategories)
    .filter(Subcategory.main_category_id == id)
    .subquery()
)

# Query for Subcategory objects and join with the subquery, filtering based on the rank
subcategories = (
    db.query(Subcategory)
    .outerjoin(subq, Subcategory.commerces)
    .options(contains_eager(Subcategory.commerces, alias=subq))
    .filter(subq.c.rn <= number_of_commerces)
    .order_by(Subcategory.id, subq.c.importance.desc())
    .all()
)
```

This code ranks the Commerce objects within each Subcategory based on their `importance`, then filters out the `Commerce` objects that don't fall within the top `number_of_commerces`. This way, you should get the top `number_of_commerces`, `Commerce` objects for each `Subcategory`.

You might need to adjust the code to fit your model definition/relationships, since I don't have the full context of your models.